# TS Server doesn't seem to recognize valid type for union in a tuple

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a function whose response is a tuple.
We either have data and no error, or we have a data mock and an error.
I'm seeming to have issues convincing TS Server of the union type.

I could use the `as` to cast it after the error check... but I shouldn't have to.
Ideas?

```
type Res = [{data: {}}, Error] | [{data: UserInfo}, null];
function getThing():Res {
// implementation
}

const [user, err] = getThing();
if (err !== null) {
  return; // TS Server should now enforce user to be of type {data: UserInfo}
}
setUserId(user.data.id); // This shows a squiggle in vscode
```

Comment: What you're creating is something called an Either Monad, if that helps. It's not something that the TypeScript compiler is smart enough to know at compile time, but can be subverted using functional programming. Although, isn't this what throwing errors is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that once you destructure `Res`, TypeScript no longer knows the relationship between `user` and `err`.

In theory, it could be possible to follow the flow to do so in simple cases like this, but in more complex cases doing so for every variable becomes extremely complicated and expensive.

Because of that, although `if (err !== null)` does narrow the type of `err`, it does not affect the type of `user`.

Fortunately, you can fix this by keeping the data as a single combined type for a little longer, like so:

```js
const result = getThing();
if (result[1] !== null) { // This now narrows the type of result, not just err
  return;
}
setUserId(result[0].data.id); // Now works fine
```

Once you're past the `if` there you're golden, so you could also use `const user = result[0]` safely and with the correct types inferred, if there's going to be more code there using that value later.